Copying 8 bytes of data from union to pointer in Structured text
I am new to structured text and barely getting started . I need to copy 8 bytes of data I receive over a CAN to another variable in structure in Structured text . Here is my code
TYPE msg :
    UNION
        data : msg_S;
        bytes : IO.CANMESSAGE;
    END_UNION
END_TYPE

TYPE msg_S :
    STRUCT
        temp1:INT;
        temp2:INT;
        temp3:INT;
        state :USINT;
        state1 :USINT;
        info : INT;
        faultcodes : POINTER TO INT;
        position : INT; 
        coolant :USINT;
        END_STRUCT
        END_TYPE

msg_data_bytes AT %Q*   : msg;

I am trying to copy data bytes I have in msg_S to faultcodes. I am trying to use memcpy as below
  memcpy(faultcodes,msg_data_bytes.bytes, 8); 

This is returning an error . How do I copy the data from msg_data_bytes.bytes to faultcodes ?

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. I really don't think you want faultcodes to be a pointer. Keep in mind that the arguments of memcpy are memory addresses, not variable names. So if you want to copy bytes to/from variable locations you need to include the ADR() operator. Ex: memcpy(ADR(varB), ADR(varA), 8)

Thank you ! All i wanted to is to move the data . ADR is what I was looking for
